# Using ng-bind directive

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to display the value in the input text field using ng-bind directive.Can someone help me with this?

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
     <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" value="ng-bind="type"">
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.type = $scope.name[0].type_of_request;
```

I am trying to print this type in html page.I am not able to achieve that.Would someone help

Comment: when you use quotes within quotes, use ' and "

Comment: this isn't what `ng-bind` is for;  why would you use this instead of `ng-model`?

Comment: `ng-model` is a two way binding. `ng-bind` simply puts the value into the element

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I'm fully aware that `ng-model` creates a two way binding.  My point, I guess, is more that this question *feels like an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).*  There isn't really any mention of what the OP is trying to do, other than "print this type in html page", and `ng-bind` is such an odd choice to use here, which wouldn't really be in *any* decent angularjs tutorial, that it's not really clear what the point is in the first place.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane and, as shown by the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5zh68a1/) created by @jitender, `ng-bind` doesn't affect the `value` *attribute* of the input anyway; it affects the *element* itself, which HTML doesn't display.  Inspect the element, you'll see it has an inner HTML that is ignored.

Comment: better yet, why not use `ng-value="type"`?  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

Comment: @Claies I have provided that in the answer below, it's pretty unclear what OP is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.type = "test";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<html ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" ng-model="type">
</div>

</html>
```

**ng-model** works to be fine here, use it:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" ng-model="type">
</div>
</html>
```

Or Use [**ng-value="type"**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

> **Check** the below example:

```html
<div ng-app="">
  <p>Enter your Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <p>Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span>!</p>
  <p>Hi <input type="text" value="{{name}}" /></p>
  <p>Ahoy <input type="text" ng-value="name" /></p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes `ng-value` also provides a one way binding. Good answer and demos.

Answer (score 2):

Use **ng-model** instead

If you need **one way** binding then

```
<input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" ng-model="::type">
```

else if you need **two way** binding

```
<input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" ng-model="type">
```

Comment: :: is for one way bind. which means it shows value of type in the input. but changing the input text will NOT change the value of type

Comment: yes i know. I was actually answering someone else's comment. someone asked why the ::?
now that person removed his comment

Comment: Sorry, @NevilleNazerane that was me. I certainly do that. Can you also add a link to the docs.

Comment: @jitender +1 from me, yes `ng-model` is definitely the way to go here. @Dinu12 `ng-bind` replaces the inner text content of the tag, and of course because this is an `<input />` tag there is no inner text content to replace, it's all in the `value` attribute. This is why `value="{{ type }}"` works and `ng-bind="type"` doesn't.

Comment: works with ng-value as well check the example above.